# FB Like dialog box not disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-like

I'm experiencing strange behavior when liking a page. The Like-dialog used to post on the liker's wall correctly but now for some reason it's not working anymore. The Send-button works fine.

I have all the og-meta tags in the head of my html and the FB Debugger finds all the correct information about the site. Here are the key lines of the button functionality:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
...
<meta property="og:title" content="Suuri Journalistipalkinto" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://suurijournalistipalkinto.fi/fi/kilpailu/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://suurijournalistipalkinto.fi/img/aanesta_like.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Suuri Journalistipalkinto" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Suuri Journalistipalkinto on jaettu Suomessa vuodesta 2001. Palkinnolla tuetaan ja edistetään hyvää journalismia. Se jaetaan joka vuosi kolmessa palkintoluokassa, palkinnon perusteena on jokin merkittävä journalistinen teko palkinnon julkistusta edeltäneen vuoden aikana." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="199611810178732" />
```

In the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

// Additional JS functions here
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '199611810178732', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
    });
...
```

And in the footer:

```
<fb:like href="http://suurijournalistipalkinto.fi/fi/kilpailu/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

If someone has ran into a similar situation, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think we're having the same issue : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13494947/post-comment-with-facebook-like-button-doesnt-work No satisfactory answer yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. This may help you...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

Code for your plugin:

```
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://suurijournalistipalkinto.fi/fi/kilpailu/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the html5-version doesn't do any better.